# How to insert hyperlinks in comments?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

Maybe I'm just making some silly mistake, but how do you create a hyperlink within a comment?

I have tried the regular html syntax, but that doesn't seem to work in comments, but it does work in answers. So what's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following code to place inline link:

```
[link description](http://example.com).
```

This also works in regular posts. However, placing too much links that way makes them hard to maintain.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not too sure whether you've noticed the hyperlink which says "**help**" underneath the Add comment while you're commenting on a question. Clicking on that will give you the best explanation and usage. Pretty simple but most do not notice it. :)

[image]

Comment: This should be upvoted as it's showing all markdown

Comment: I hadn't noticed the help button before... but it's staring me in the face now.

Comment: That's why most say; "Noticing even smaller things makes wonder at times". :)